# Check login and logout openldap userss

Tags: openldap

I have a server ldap Ubuntu with Xubuntu like clients now I need to audit the times when an user login and logout of one machine.

Is there a way to see the information of login and logout from openldap server

Comment: There's no reason for information to sent to the LDAP server during logout, and during login, if the client caches data, it's possible nothing is sent to the server. You should do this on the client.

Comment: I need to audit the in/out from my users but when I can get this info. Just script in logon , I can do this in Windows Active directory